# how to return response to postman using nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning nodejs with express. So i have connected mongodb and fetching data from db using nodejs. When i hit the url from postman, i can able to retrieve data but the problem is can't able to return response to postman. I can see the result in console. if i tried **setTimeout** , it's working fine .. but that is not a proper way to do it. I tried res.send() method to return response but of no use. Kindly help me to solve this

```
 app.post('/getmongo',function (req,res){
    console.log("I received a request");
    console.log(req.body.filters)
    filters = req.body.filters
    console.log(typeof filters)
    var ism = []
    db.collection('collection_name').find(filters,function(err,data){
         if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.send(500,'something went wrong')
         }
         else{

             data.each(function(err,doc){
                 console.log(doc)
                 ism.push(doc)
             });
             setTimeout(function(){res.send({"ISM":ism})},1000)
         }
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` parameter is not "Your data" :D , It is a `Cursor` object, and `each` function is a async function. Without `setTimeout`, `data.each` (not like Array.prototype.forEach) and `res.send({"ISM":ism})` will run in the same time (`ism` now is []).

If you want keep using `cusor method`, you have to change some of code:

```
data.each(function(err,doc){
    if(doc !== null) {
        console.log(doc)
        ism.push(doc)
    } else {
        // close you db connection...
        res.send({"ISM":ism})
    }
});
```

Or, you could use `.toArray` method (if you are using `require('mongodb').MongoClient`) to get `data` back:

```
db.collection('collection_name').find(filters).toArray(function(err, items){
    if(err){
       console.log(err)
       return res.send(500,'something went wrong')
    }
    else{
        res.send({"ISM": items})
    }
})
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating within the data and inserting the result in an array, you could return the find result as an array.

Therefore, your function will look something like this:

```
app.post('/getmongo', function(req, res) {
    filters = req.body.filters;
    db.collection('collection_name').find(filters).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(500, 'something went wrong');
        } else {
            res.send({"ISM": docs});

            // If you want to return JSON
            // res.json({"ISM": docs});
        }
    });
});
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/#find-documents-with-a-query-filter

Answer (score 0):

It is sending the null data because of its asynchronous nature.

You can use a hack like this.

```
data.each(function(err,doc){
            console.log(doc)
            ism.push(doc)
            if(data.length === ism.length) {
              res.send({"ISM":ism})
            }
 });
```

Comment: Inside the each loop you should not send response . In console is still running and getting data but before completing the response , getting cannot read property lenght undefined error in postman

Comment: It is not sending the data in each iteration. Please see the code carefully.